# Aggregate variables separetly in R [lapply + aggregate]

Tags: r, aggregate, lapply

I have a `data.frame` with a set of records and as variables different measurements. I would like to create a new `data.frame` containing the amount of records having a specific measurement value for each measurement. Basically what I am trying to do is:

```
record <- c("r1", "r2", "r3") 
firstMeasurement <- c(15, 10, 10) 
secondMeasurement <- c(2, 4, 2) 
df <- data.frame(record, firstMeasurement, secondMeasurement)

measurements <- c(colnames(df[2:3]))
measuramentsAggregate <- lapply(measurements, function(i) 
                  aggregate(record~i, df, FUN=length))
```

I am getting really funny errors and I don't understand why. Can anyone help me?

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you try `as.formula(sprintf('record~%s',i))` instead of `record~i`?

Comment: Or instead of the formula method, you can use `lapply(measurements, function(x) aggregate(df$record, list(df[,x]), FUN=length))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
library(dplyr)
agg.measurements <- df %>% group_by(firstMeasurement) %>% summarise(records=n())
```

That should do it for the one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of records with specific `firstMeasurement`:

```
table(df$firstMeasurement)
```

Likewise for the `secondMeasurement`. I am not sure how the `data.frame` you are trying to create might look.